# Launching SLURM jobs on cluster from new git branch

Tags: git, jobs, slurm

I have some code with two git branches, `branch 1` and `branch 2`. I have been launching SLURM jobs using a shell script  on a computing cluster (via `sbatch shell_script.sh` in the terminal) to run a Julia script `my_code.jl` contained in `branch 1`.

I would now like to modify `my_code.jl` without affecting previously submitted jobs, such that those jobs run with the old version of `my_code.jl`. I thus created `branch 2` for my new code fixes.

My question is: if I switch to `branch 2` and launch new jobs running `my_code.jl` via `sbatch shell_script.sh` (which is the same as on `branch 1` ), will git run the version of `my_code.jl` on `branch 2`, and will previously submitted jobs continue to run the version of `my_code.jl` on `branch 1`? If so, how does SLURM know to do this, given that in the  `shell_script.sh` the line running my code `julia my_code.jl` does not refer to any given git branch.

Edit:

I did a quick test to see if this is true, and it appears to be false. I.e I submitted a job while on the old branch, and switched to the new branch and submitted the same job again. What happened was the code on the new branch ran in both cases.

This would mean I can't safely work on the new branch and expect SLURM jobs I previously submitted to not be affected..

Comment: *Git* doesn't run any of these. Something else (presumably [slurm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slurm_Workload_Manager)) runs them. How and when is up to that something-else.

Comment: @torek indeed, I meant how does SLURM know to do this, given that in the sbatch shell_script.sh the line running my code julia my_code.jl does not refer to any given git branch

Comment: One would hope this is answered in the SLURM documentation. :-) Some job-running systems make a copy of the "job to be run" at the time you submit it, which is a pretty reliable way to gain their own snapshot that can't change, which is usually a good plan. Whether this one does that, I don't know. In this case that would probably grab a copy of the reference to the file, but not necessarily a copy of the file itself, *unless* they use the same kind of FUSE trick that Docker uses to snapshot file systems.

Comment: @torek equivalently, I am asking which git branch does SLURM "see", and if the answer is simply "your current HEAD", why?

Comment: @torek indeed, SLURM takes a snapshot of the shell script, but not of the julia code. That is precisely why I am asking this question. If I modify the julia code on a new git branch, will slurm run my modified code when launching jobs on the new branch, while not affecting previously submitted jobs launched from the old branch? I hope the question is clear, let me know if I  should clarify.

Comment: Well, now I'm back to the obvious question to which *I* have no idea what the answer is: how does SLURM, which seems to treat a large set of Linux boxes as a single "virtual machine", present the *same file system* to processes regardless of which *machine* the process runs on? It must do something file-system-y to do that. Presumably the script either runs Git commands or doesn't, and either way, the commands it runs see "a file system": but which one? Where do they get it? That would answer your question, but *I don't know the answer*.